# Why is InDesign rasterizing my Illustrator placed files?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am new to InDesign and have used Illustrator for many years.

I am using the place command in Indesign of an AI file into my InDesign file, but when I do that its like Indesign is rasterizing it or something. I have looked at videos online of people placing AI files in and there's look how it does in AI, but when I do it, the graphic is all screwed.

Is there a reason why it is doing this? Copying and pasting from AI into InD is no problems, it works fine but I need to use place as I will be making changes.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Try changing the art to high quality. InDesign  defaults to a preview mode that is less than perfect otherwise to conserve your computers computational resources. Oh and wellcome  to GD.SE

Comment: Thank you so much for that :) Its strange that if I paste from AI into IND its no problems, but I guess Placing is different. It also solved another issue I had with a particular image that was banding so you hit a bird with two stones there :)

Comment: I think it wasn't rasterizing the graphics that you placed.  It was just the fast display/visualization mode.  When you pasted from AI to IND I bet you it *was* rasterizing, and fast display mode just displayed the image at better resolution.